# How does Scala's type erasure work for higher kinded type parameters?

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure, higher-kinded-types, scala-compiler

I don't understand *which* generic type parameters Scala erases. I used to think that it should erase *all* generic type parameters, but this does not seem to be the case.

Correct me if I'm wrong: if I instantiate an instance of type `Map[Int, String]` in the code, then at the runtime, the instance knows only that it is of type `Map[_, _]`, and does not know anything about its generic type parameters. This is why the following succeeds to compile and to execute without errors:

```
val x: Map[Int, String] = Map(2 -> "a")
val y: Map[String, Int] = x.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Int]]
```

Now I would expect that all higher-kinded type parameters are also erased, that is, if I have a

```
class Foo[H[_, _], X, Y]
```

I would expect that an instance of type `Foo[Map, Int, String]` knows nothing about `Map`. But now consider the following sequence of type-cast "experiments":

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

def cast1[A](a: Any): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
def cast2[H[_, _], A, B](a: Any) = a.asInstanceOf[H[A, B]]
def cast3[F[_[_, _], _, _], H[_, _], X, Y](a: Any) = a.asInstanceOf[F[H, X, Y]]
class CastTo[H[_, _], A, B] {
  def cast(x: Any): H[A, B] = x.asInstanceOf[H[A, B]]
}

ignoreException {
  val v1 = cast1[String](List[Int](1, 2, 3))                      
  // throws ClassCastException
}

ignoreException {
  val v2 = cast2[Map, Int, Long](Map[String, Double]("a" -> 1.0)) 
  // doesn't complain at all, `A` and `B` erased
}

ignoreException {
  // right kind
  val v3 = cast2[Map, Int, Long]((x: Int) => x.toLong)            
  // throws ClassCastException
}

ignoreException {
  // wrong kind
  val v4 = cast2[Map, Int, Long]("wrong kind")                     
  // throws ClassCastException
}

ignoreException {
  class Foo[H[_, _], X, Y](h: H[X, Y])
  val x = new Foo[Function, Int, String](n => "#" * n)
  val v5 = cast3[Foo, Map, Int, Long](x)
  // nothing happens, happily replaces `Function` by `Map`
}

ignoreException {
  val v6 = (new CastTo[Map, Int, Long]).cast(List("hello?"))       
  // throws ClassCastException
}

ignoreException {
  val castToMap = new CastTo[Map, Int, Long]
  val v7 = castToMap.cast("how can it detect this?")               
  // throws ClassCastException
}

ignoreException {
  val castToMap = new CastTo[Map, Int, Long]
  val madCast = castToMap.asInstanceOf[CastTo[Function, Float, Double]]
  val v8 = madCast.cast("what does it detect at all?")
  // String cannot be cast to Function???
  // Why does it retain any information about `Function` here?
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------------
var ignoreBlockCounter = 0
/** Executes piece of code, 
  * catches an exeption (if one is thrown),
  * prints number of `ignoreException`-wrapped block,
  * prints name of the exception.
  */
def ignoreException[U](f: => U): Unit = {
  ignoreBlockCounter += 1
  try {
    f
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      println("[" + ignoreBlockCounter + "]" + e)
  }
}
```

Here is the output (scala -version 2.12.4):

```
[1]java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[3]java.lang.ClassCastException: Main$$anon$1$$Lambda$143/1744347043 cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
[4]java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
[6]java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
[7]java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map
[8]java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.Function1
```

- The cases 1, 3, 4 indicate that `asInstanceOf[Foo[...]]` does care about `Foo`, this is expected.
- The case 2 indicates that `asInstanceOf[Foo[X,Y]]` does *not* care about `X` and `Y`, this is also expected.
- The case 5 indicates that `asInstanceOf` does *not* care about higher kinded type parameter `Map`, similar to case 2, this is also expected.

So far so good. However, the cases 6, 7, 8 suggest a different behavior: here, an instance of type `CastTo[Foo, X, Y]` seems to retain information about the generic type parameter `Foo` for some reason. More precisely, a `CastTo[Map, Int, Long]` seems to carry around enough information with it to know that a string cannot be cast into a `Map`. Moreover, in case 8, it seems to even change `Map` to `Function` because of a cast.

Question(s):

1. Is my understanding correct that the first generic parameter of `CastTo` is not erased, or is there something else what I don't see? Some implicit operation or anything?
2. Is there any documentation that describes this behavior?
3. Is there any reason why I should *want* this behavior? I find it somewhat counter-intuitive, but maybe it's just me, and I'm using the tool wrong...

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**: Poking around in similar examples revealed an issue with the 2.12.4-compiler (see my own "answer" below), but this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing some things.

Casts to generic types are deferred until the point where the types become concrete. For example, take this piece of code:

```
class CastTo[H[_, _], A, B] {
  def cast(x: Any): H[A, B] = x.asInstanceOf[H[A, B]]
}
```

In the bytecode you can only cast to a real class, because it doesn't know anything about generics. So the above will, in bytecode, be roughly equivalent to:

```
class CastTo {
  def cast(x: Object): Object = x
}
```

Then later in the code you give a `String` to method `cast` and the compiler can see that according to the type information it has, a `Map[Int, Long]` will come out. But in the bytecode `cast` has an erased return type of `Object`, so the compiler has to insert a cast at the *use-site* of the `cast` method. This code

```
val castToMap = new CastTo[Map, Int, Long]
val v7 = castToMap.cast("how can it detect this?")
```

will, in the bytecode, be roughly equivalent to the following (pseudo) code:

```
val castToMap = new CastTo
val v7 = castToMap.cast("how can it detect this?").asInstanceOf[Map]
```

As for your other questions:

2. Not that I immediately know of.
3. Why would you *not* want it? You are casting a `String` to a `Map[Int, Long]`. That is bound to crash eventually. Failing (relatively) fast with a `ClassCastException` is probably the safest, most user-friendly option.

Comment: "so the compiler has to insert a cast at the _use-site_ of the cast method" - That was the missing piece. Thank you for pointing out the distinction between the definition site and the use site in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's probably not the expected behavior.

Here is a randomized version of the above:

```
ignoreException {
  class Foo[X, Y]
  class Bar[X, Y]

  val castToMap = new CastTo[Map, Int, Long]
  val madderCast = if (math.random() > 0.5) {
    println("Foo")
    castToMap.asInstanceOf[CastTo[Foo, Float, Double]]
  } else {
    println("Bar")
    castToMap.asInstanceOf[CastTo[Bar, String, Any]]
  }
  val v9 = madderCast.cast("crash 'dis serva, awww yeah!")
  // crashes the compile server for scala 2.12.4
  // dotty 0.4.0-RC1 doesn't complain at all (as expected!)
}
```

crashes the 2.12.4 compiler. Dotty has no problems.

**EDIT** Shorter, self-contained example:

import scala.language.higherKinds

```
class Foo[X]
class Bar[X]
class CrashIt[A[_]] {
  def cast(a: Any): A[Int] = a.asInstanceOf[A[Int]]
}
val c = if (true) new CrashIt[Foo] else new CrashIt[Bar]
val x = c.cast("")
```

Crashes with:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:428)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:425)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.ContextErrors$InferencerContextErrors$InferErrorGen$.
      NotWithinBoundsErrorMessage(ContextErrors.scala:1045)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.ContextErrors$InferencerContextErrors$InferErrorGen$.
      NotWithinBoundsContextErrors.scala:1052)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.issueBoundsError$1(Infer.scala:881)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.check$1(Infer.scala:887)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$Inferencer.checkBounds(Infer.scala:891)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.checkBounds(RefChecks.scala:1203)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.checkTypeRef(RefChecks.scala:1384)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transform$4(RefChecks.scala:1668)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transform$4$adapted(RefChecks.scala:1659)
    at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeMaps$ForEachTypeTraverser.traverse(TypeMaps.scala:1102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.foreach(Types.scala:787)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1407)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$1(Trees.scala:1369)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1368)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1186)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1416)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2563)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$4(Trees.scala:1420)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1419)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1198)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1378)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$2(Trees.scala:1375)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1373)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1198)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1416)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2563)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$5(Trees.scala:1425)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1424)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1198)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.$anonfun$transformStats$1(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1169)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.$anonfun$itransform$7(Trees.scala:1438)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform(Trees.scala:1438)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees.itransform$(Trees.scala:1348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1751)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:107)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:140)
    at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$applyPhase$1(Global.scala:436)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:429)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1(Global.scala:400)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(Global.scala:400)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:400)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1452)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1436)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1429)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1545)
    at scala.tools.nsc.StandardCompileServer.session(CompileServer.scala:150)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.$anonfun$doSession$2(SocketServer.scala:80)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:163)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.$anonfun$doSession$1(SocketServer.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.$anonfun$doSession$1$adapted(SocketServer.scala:75)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.Socket.applyReaderAndWriter(Socket.scala:49)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.doSession(SocketServer.scala:75)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.loop$1(SocketServer.scala:91)
    at scala.tools.util.SocketServer.run(SocketServer.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer$.$anonfun$execute$3(CompileServer.scala:216)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:12)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:163)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer$.$anonfun$execute$2(CompileServer.scala:211)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:12)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at scala.Console$.withErr(Console.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer$.main(CompileServer.scala:211)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CompileServer.main(CompileServer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:34)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:30)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:99)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:91)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:66)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:85)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

The casting step seems to be crucial. If the invocation of `cast` is removed, nothing happens.

This does not happen if the parameter `A` is not higher-kinded, so for example for `class CrashIt[A]` and `new CrashIt[Int]` the compiler does not complain.

**EDIT-2**: Couldn't find this exact bug (or an obvious generalization thereof), reported it here: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10700 .

Comment: This is probably a compiler bug because it should never crash (although some StackOverflowErrors might be exceptions to this rule), but unrelated to casting. You'll get the same with `val c = if (true) new CastTo[Foo, Float, Double] else new CastTo[Bar, Float, Double]`.

Comment: The reason Dotty doesn't crash is partly because it can represent more types and its type system probably has more solid foundations. The reason it doesn't throw a `ClassCastException` is because `v9` will still have a more or less generic type that the JVM can't represent, thus has to be erased to `Object`.

Comment: @Jasper-M this is clearly a compiler bug. I haven't yet tried to make the code as short as possible, but your example with two `new CastTo`s seems to work just fine, strangely enough. I suspect that the solution to this kind of bugs is something like "invent more solid foundations, implement Dotty" :]

Comment: Strange. When I compile my snippet in the REPL it crashes with StackOverflowError.

Comment: When I run the "if ( ... ) ... asInstanceOf" version, it crashes with a "java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list". That's a slightly different way to crash: instead of recursing indefinitely and hoping for brighter future, it ends up with a very concrete list which must not be empty, but is empty. I'll write up a compressed example that leads to the error.

Comment: You're right. Here's one that crashes with the same exception: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Jasper-M/7vEZQdAXSlCj0Wb8GBlBpA
Mine only crashed the REPL for some strange reason.